# Can Chart.js combines Line Chart and Bar Chart in one canvas

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.js to display the data of Blood pressure, which include three sets of data(pulse, systolic, diastolic). the pulse data should display as line chart while systolic, and diastolic will be in bar chart. So I wondering there should be a way to combine them together.

PS. the updated Chart js provide the Stacked Bar Chart, which is pretty good to learn as the beginning of customizing Chart js.

Comment: sorry for the late post, [you should check here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811425/chart-js-how-to-get-combined-bar-and-line-charts

Comment: This post provide a great work for the answer, awesome!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25828230/2512793

Comment: charts.js now supports combined bar and line chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811425/chart-js-how-to-get-combined-bar-and-line-charts/34987415#34987415

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, as is documented by this outstanding issue.

https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/799