# Chart.js how to get Combined Bar and line charts?

Tags: charts, chart.js

i would like to ask is that possible using Chart.js http://www.chartjs.org/ to get Combined Bar and line charts?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: was the below answer what you were looking for?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, seems to be a good solution.  Nice work.

Comment: Cheers, if you use it let me know how you get on with it and if there are any oddities :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

#### The below answer is concerned with chart.js 1.x. Chart.js 2.x supports this [Chart.js how to get Combined Bar and line charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811425/chart-js-how-to-get-combined-bar-and-line-charts/34987415#34987415)

**EDIT 2** I have now added this feature to my custom build of chartjs if you want to use that https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js the only difference is i named it Overlay not LineBar so to use it just create a graph using `var myOverlayChart = new Chart(lineBar).Overlay(data);` everything else is the same though.

---

Ok so had a quick go at seeing if this was possible and the short answer is yes but would need more work truly integrate this into the build of chart js. Here is a fiddle showing it in action with a line and bar chart to compare against: http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/898kzyp7/

So my solution was to create a new chart type called LineBar (could have gone for the extending option but before starting I felt like this was going to need a lot of method overriding so went for a new graph, it also means i didn't have to re-declare helpers as Chart.helpers not a huge thing but was reason enough at the time).

At it's core it is the bar chart but it keeps a track of datasets in separate `lineDataSets` and `barDataSets` variables. Then when it needs to draw/check-events /use-the-data it loops other both of the new datasets separately.

Whenever it is looping over the `lineDataSets` variable it is performing code from the current line graph and visa versa for the bar graph

So i'll paste the new graph  at the bottom of this answer as it's pretty large, to use it copy and paste it into your own chart.js file at the bottom or paste it after you include chart.js on your page.

To then make use of it you can now declare your data with an extra option called `type`

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        //new option, type will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
        type: "line",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 4, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }, {
        label: "My First dataset",
        //new option, type will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
        type: "bar",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,20,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [32, 25, 33, 88, 12, 92, 33]
    }]
};
```

then just create a new chart of type LineBar

```
var lineBar = document.getElementById("line-bar").getContext("2d");
var myLineBarChart = new Chart(lineBar).LineBar(data);
```

result

[image: linebar]

**EDIT:** Updated it so now it has the tooltips and removeData/addData functionality working. See the fiddle for examples of these. You can also add as many datasets as you like both line and bar and it will display them all on the same graph.

Limitation - if bar and line get updated their respective pieces have to be updated here as well which isn't great, they won't break if bar and line get updated it just might mean they don't look the same whatever gets updated

and here is the actual new chart

```
//new chart type LineBar - its a bit like bar and line 
//were slammed together at high speed, not pretty, 
//but they are part of each other now
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var root = this,
        Chart = root.Chart,
        helpers = Chart.helpers;


    var defaultConfig = {
        //Function - Whether the current x-axis label should be filtered out, takes in current label and 
        //index, return true to filter out the label return false to keep the label
        labelsFilter : function(label,index){return false;},

        //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,

        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines : true,

        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke : true,

        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth : 2,

        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing : 5,

        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing : 1,

        //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
        bezierCurve : true,

        //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
        bezierCurveTension : 0.4,

        //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
        pointDot : true,

        //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
        pointDotRadius : 4,

        //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
        pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,

        //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
        pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,

        //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
        datasetStroke : true,

        //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
        datasetStrokeWidth : 2,

        //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a colour
        datasetFill : true,

        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

    };


    Chart.Type.extend({
        name: "LineBar",
        defaults : defaultConfig,
        initialize:  function(data){
            //Expose options as a scope variable here so we can access it in the ScaleClass
            var options = this.options;
            //two new varibale to hold the different graph types
            this.barDatasets = [];
            this.lineDatasets = [];

            //generate the scale, let bar take control here as he needs the width.
            this.ScaleClass = Chart.Scale.extend({
                offsetGridLines : true,
                calculateBarX : function(datasetCount, datasetIndex, barIndex){
                    //Reusable method for calculating the xPosition of a given bar based on datasetIndex & width of the bar
                    var xWidth = this.calculateBaseWidth(),
                        xAbsolute = this.calculateX(barIndex) - (xWidth/2),
                        barWidth = this.calculateBarWidth(datasetCount);

                    return xAbsolute + (barWidth * datasetIndex) + (datasetIndex * options.barDatasetSpacing) + barWidth/2;
                },
                calculateBaseWidth : function(){
                    return (this.calculateX(1) - this.calculateX(0)) - (2*options.barValueSpacing);
                },
                calculateBarWidth : function(datasetCount){
                    //The padding between datasets is to the right of each bar, providing that there are more than 1 dataset
                    var baseWidth = this.calculateBaseWidth() - ((datasetCount - 1) * options.barDatasetSpacing);

                    return (baseWidth / datasetCount);
                }
            });

            //Declare the extension of the default point, to cater for the options passed in to the constructor
            this.PointClass = Chart.Point.extend({
                strokeWidth : this.options.pointDotStrokeWidth,
                radius : this.options.pointDotRadius,
                display: this.options.pointDot,
                hitDetectionRadius : this.options.pointHitDetectionRadius,
                ctx : this.chart.ctx,
                inRange : function(mouseX){
                    return (Math.pow(mouseX-this.x, 2) < Math.pow(this.radius + this.hitDetectionRadius,2));
                }
            });

            this.datasets = [];

            //Set up tooltip events on the chart
            if (this.options.showTooltips){
                helpers.bindEvents(this, this.options.tooltipEvents, function(evt){
                    var activeData = (evt.type !== 'mouseout') ? this.getDataAtEvent(evt) : [];
                    this.eachBars(function(bar){
                        bar.restore(['fillColor', 'strokeColor']);
                    });
                    this.eachPoints(function(point){
                        point.restore(['fillColor', 'strokeColor']);
                    });
                    helpers.each(activeData, function(active){
                        active.fillColor = active.highlightFill;
                        active.strokeColor = active.highlightStroke;
                    });
                    this.showTooltip(activeData);
                });
            }

            //Declare the extension of the default point, to cater for the options passed in to the constructor
            this.BarClass = Chart.Rectangle.extend({
                strokeWidth : this.options.barStrokeWidth,
                showStroke : this.options.barShowStroke,
                ctx : this.chart.ctx
            });

            //Iterate through each of the datasets, and build this into a property of the chart
            helpers.each(data.datasets,function(dataset,datasetIndex){

                var datasetObject = {
                    label : dataset.label || null,
                    fillColor : dataset.fillColor,
                    strokeColor : dataset.strokeColor,
                    type: dataset.type,
                    bars : [],
                    pointColor : dataset.pointColor,
                    pointStrokeColor : dataset.pointStrokeColor,
                    points : []
                };

                this.datasets.push(datasetObject);
                switch(dataset.type)
                {
                    case "line":
                    this.lineDatasets.push(datasetObject);
                    helpers.each(dataset.data,function(dataPoint,index){
                        //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
                        datasetObject.points.push(new this.PointClass({
                            value : dataPoint,
                            label : data.labels[index],
                            datasetLabel: dataset.label,
                            strokeColor : dataset.pointStrokeColor,
                            fillColor : dataset.pointColor,
                            highlightFill : dataset.pointHighlightFill || dataset.pointColor,
                            highlightStroke : dataset.pointHighlightStroke || dataset.pointStrokeColor
                        }));
                    },this);
                    break;

                    default:
                        this.barDatasets.push(datasetObject);
                        helpers.each(dataset.data,function(dataPoint,index){
                            //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
                            datasetObject.bars.push(new this.BarClass({
                                value : dataPoint,
                                label : data.labels[index],
                                datasetLabel: dataset.label,
                                strokeColor : dataset.strokeColor,
                                fillColor : dataset.fillColor,
                                highlightFill : dataset.highlightFill || dataset.fillColor,
                                highlightStroke : dataset.highlightStroke || dataset.strokeColor
                            }));
                        },this);

                    break;
                }


            },this);

            this.buildScale(data.labels);

            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets,function(dataset,datasetIndex){
                //Iterate through each of the datasets, and build this into a property of the chart
                    this.eachPoints(function(point, index){
                        helpers.extend(point, {
                            x: this.scale.calculateX(index),
                            y: this.scale.endPoint
                        });
                        point.save();
                    }, this);
                },this);

            this.BarClass.prototype.base = this.scale.endPoint;
            this.eachBars(function(bar, index, datasetIndex){
                helpers.extend(bar, {
                    width : this.scale.calculateBarWidth(this.barDatasets.length),
                    x: this.scale.calculateBarX(this.barDatasets.length, datasetIndex, index),
                    y: this.scale.endPoint
                });
                bar.save();
            }, this);

            this.render();
        },
        update : function(){
            this.scale.update();
            // Reset any highlight colours before updating.
            helpers.each(this.activeElements, function(activeElement){
                activeElement.restore(['fillColor', 'strokeColor']);
            });

            this.eachBars(function(bar){
                bar.save();
            });
            this.eachPoints(function(point){
                point.save();
            });
            this.render();
        },
        eachPoints : function(callback){
            //use the lineDataSets
            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets,function(dataset){
                    helpers.each(dataset.points,callback,this);
            },this);
        },
        eachBars : function(callback){
            //user the barDataSets
            helpers.each(this.barDatasets,function(dataset, datasetIndex){
                    helpers.each(dataset.bars, callback, this, datasetIndex);
            },this);
        },


        getDataAtEvent : function(e)
        {

                return this.getPointsAtEvent(e).concat(this.getBarsAtEvent(e));
        },
        getPointsAtEvent : function(e){
            var pointsArray = [],
                eventPosition = helpers.getRelativePosition(e);
            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets,function(dataset){
                helpers.each(dataset.points,function(point){
                    if (point.inRange(eventPosition.x,eventPosition.y)) pointsArray.push(point);
                });
            },this);
            return pointsArray;
        },
        getBarsAtEvent : function(e){
            var barsArray = [],
                eventPosition = helpers.getRelativePosition(e),
                datasetIterator = function(dataset){
                    barsArray.push(dataset.bars[barIndex]);
                },
                barIndex;

            for (var datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < this.barDatasets.length; datasetIndex++) {
                for (barIndex = 0; barIndex < this.barDatasets[datasetIndex].bars.length; barIndex++) {
                    if (this.barDatasets[datasetIndex].bars[barIndex].inRange(eventPosition.x,eventPosition.y)){
                        helpers.each(this.barDatasets, datasetIterator);
                        return barsArray;
                    }
                }
            }

            return barsArray;
        },
        buildScale : function(labels){
            var self = this;

            var dataTotal = function(){
                var values = [];
                self.eachBars(function(bar){
                    values.push(bar.value);
                });
                return values;
            };

            var scaleOptions = {
                labelsFilter: this.options.labelsFilter,
                templateString : this.options.scaleLabel,
                height : this.chart.height,
                width : this.chart.width,
                ctx : this.chart.ctx,
                textColor : this.options.scaleFontColor,
                fontSize : this.options.scaleFontSize,
                fontStyle : this.options.scaleFontStyle,
                fontFamily : this.options.scaleFontFamily,
                valuesCount : labels.length,
                beginAtZero : this.options.scaleBeginAtZero,
                integersOnly : this.options.scaleIntegersOnly,
                calculateYRange: function(currentHeight){
                    var updatedRanges = helpers.calculateScaleRange(
                        dataTotal(),
                        currentHeight,
                        this.fontSize,
                        this.beginAtZero,
                        this.integersOnly
                    );
                    helpers.extend(this, updatedRanges);
                },
                xLabels : labels,
                font : helpers.fontString(this.options.scaleFontSize, this.options.scaleFontStyle, this.options.scaleFontFamily),
                lineWidth : this.options.scaleLineWidth,
                lineColor : this.options.scaleLineColor,
                gridLineWidth : (this.options.scaleShowGridLines) ? this.options.scaleGridLineWidth : 0,
                gridLineColor : (this.options.scaleShowGridLines) ? this.options.scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                padding : (this.options.showScale) ? 0 : (this.options.barShowStroke) ? this.options.barStrokeWidth : 0,
                showLabels : this.options.scaleShowLabels,
                display : this.options.showScale
            };

            if (this.options.scaleOverride){
                helpers.extend(scaleOptions, {
                    calculateYRange: helpers.noop,
                    steps: this.options.scaleSteps,
                    stepValue: this.options.scaleStepWidth,
                    min: this.options.scaleStartValue,
                    max: this.options.scaleStartValue + (this.options.scaleSteps * this.options.scaleStepWidth)
                });
            }

            this.scale = new this.ScaleClass(scaleOptions);
        },
        addData : function(valuesArray,label){
            //Map the values array for each of the datasets

            var lineDataSetIndex = 0;
            var barDataSetIndex = 0;
            helpers.each(valuesArray,function(value,datasetIndex){
                switch(this.datasets[datasetIndex].type)
                {
                    case "line":
                        //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
                        this.lineDatasets[lineDataSetIndex].points.push(new this.PointClass({
                            value : value,
                            label : label,
                            x: this.scale.calculateX(this.scale.valuesCount+1),
                            y: this.scale.endPoint,
                            strokeColor : this.lineDatasets[lineDataSetIndex].pointStrokeColor,
                            fillColor : this.lineDatasets[lineDataSetIndex].pointColor
                        }));
                        lineDataSetIndex++;
                    break;

                    default:
                        //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
                        this.barDatasets[barDataSetIndex].bars.push(new this.BarClass({
                            value : value,
                            label : label,
                            x: this.scale.calculateBarX(this.barDatasets.length, barDataSetIndex, this.scale.valuesCount+1),
                            y: this.scale.endPoint,
                            width : this.scale.calculateBarWidth(this.barDatasets.length),
                            base : this.scale.endPoint,
                            strokeColor : this.barDatasets[barDataSetIndex].strokeColor,
                            fillColor : this.barDatasets[barDataSetIndex].fillColor
                        }));
                        barDataSetIndex++;
                    break;
                }
            },this);
            this.scale.addXLabel(label);
            //Then re-render the chart.
            this.update();
        },
        removeData : function(){
            this.scale.removeXLabel();
            //Then re-render the chart.
            helpers.each(this.barDatasets,function(dataset){
                dataset.bars.shift();
            },this);

            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets,function(dataset){
                dataset.points.shift();
            },this);

            this.update();
        },
        reflow : function(){
            helpers.extend(this.BarClass.prototype,{
                y: this.scale.endPoint,
                base : this.scale.endPoint
            });
            var newScaleProps = helpers.extend({
                height : this.chart.height,
                width : this.chart.width
            });
            this.scale.update(newScaleProps);
        },
        draw : function(ease){
            var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
            this.clear();

            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

            // Some helper methods for getting the next/prev points
            var hasValue = function(item){
                return item.value !== null;
            },
            nextPoint = function(point, collection, index){
                return helpers.findNextWhere(collection, hasValue, index) || point;
            },
            previousPoint = function(point, collection, index){
                return helpers.findPreviousWhere(collection, hasValue, index) || point;
            };

            this.scale.draw(easingDecimal);

            //Draw all the bars for each dataset
            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets,function(dataset,datasetIndex){
                var pointsWithValues = helpers.where(dataset.points, hasValue);
                //Transition each point first so that the line and point drawing isn't out of sync
                //We can use this extra loop to calculate the control points of this dataset also in this loop
                helpers.each(dataset.points, function(point, index){
                    if (point.hasValue()){
                        point.transition({
                            y : this.scale.calculateY(point.value),
                            x : this.scale.calculateX(index)
                        }, easingDecimal);
                    }
                },this);

                // Control points need to be calculated in a seperate loop, because we need to know the current x/y of the point
                // This would cause issues when there is no animation, because the y of the next point would be 0, so beziers would be skewed
                if (this.options.bezierCurve){
                    helpers.each(pointsWithValues, function(point, index){
                        var tension = (index > 0 && index < pointsWithValues.length - 1) ? this.options.bezierCurveTension : 0;
                        point.controlPoints = helpers.splineCurve(
                            previousPoint(point, pointsWithValues, index),
                            point,
                            nextPoint(point, pointsWithValues, index),
                            tension
                        );

                        // Prevent the bezier going outside of the bounds of the graph

                        // Cap puter bezier handles to the upper/lower scale bounds
                        if (point.controlPoints.outer.y > this.scale.endPoint){
                            point.controlPoints.outer.y = this.scale.endPoint;
                        }
                        else if (point.controlPoints.outer.y < this.scale.startPoint){
                            point.controlPoints.outer.y = this.scale.startPoint;
                        }

                        // Cap inner bezier handles to the upper/lower scale bounds
                        if (point.controlPoints.inner.y > this.scale.endPoint){
                            point.controlPoints.inner.y = this.scale.endPoint;
                        }
                        else if (point.controlPoints.inner.y < this.scale.startPoint){
                            point.controlPoints.inner.y = this.scale.startPoint;
                        }
                    },this);
                }


                //Draw the line between all the points
                ctx.lineWidth = this.options.datasetStrokeWidth;
                ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.strokeColor;
                ctx.beginPath();

                helpers.each(pointsWithValues, function(point, index){
                    if (index === 0){
                        ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(this.options.bezierCurve){
                            var previous = previousPoint(point, pointsWithValues, index);

                            ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                                previous.controlPoints.outer.x,
                                previous.controlPoints.outer.y,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.x,
                                point.controlPoints.inner.y,
                                point.x,
                                point.y
                            );
                        }
                        else{
                            ctx.lineTo(point.x,point.y);
                        }
                    }
                }, this);

                ctx.stroke();

                if (this.options.datasetFill && pointsWithValues.length > 0){
                    //Round off the line by going to the base of the chart, back to the start, then fill.
                    ctx.lineTo(pointsWithValues[pointsWithValues.length - 1].x, this.scale.endPoint);
                    ctx.lineTo(pointsWithValues[0].x, this.scale.endPoint);
                    ctx.fillStyle = dataset.fillColor;
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }

                //Now draw the points over the line
                //A little inefficient double looping, but better than the line
                //lagging behind the point positions
                helpers.each(pointsWithValues,function(point){
                    point.draw();
                });


            },this);
            helpers.each(this.barDatasets,function(dataset,datasetIndex){
                        helpers.each(dataset.bars,function(bar,index){
                            if (bar.hasValue()){
                                bar.base = this.scale.endPoint;
                                //Transition then draw
                                bar.transition({
                                    x : this.scale.calculateBarX(this.barDatasets.length, datasetIndex, index),
                                    y : this.scale.calculateY(bar.value),
                                    width : this.scale.calculateBarWidth(this.barDatasets.length)
                                }, easingDecimal).draw();
                            }
                        },this);
            },this);
        },
        showTooltip : function(ChartElements, forceRedraw){
            // Only redraw the chart if we've actually changed what we're hovering on.
            if (typeof this.activeElements === 'undefined') this.activeElements = [];

            var isChanged = (function(Elements){
                var changed = false;

                if (Elements.length !== this.activeElements.length){
                    changed = true;
                    return changed;
                }

                helpers.each(Elements, function(element, index){
                    if (element !== this.activeElements[index]){
                        changed = true;
                    }
                }, this);
                return changed;
            }).call(this, ChartElements);

            if (!isChanged && !forceRedraw){
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.activeElements = ChartElements;
            }
            this.draw();
            if (ChartElements.length > 0){
                // If we have multiple datasets, show a MultiTooltip for all of the data points at that index
                if (this.datasets && this.datasets.length > 1) {
                    var dataArray,
                        dataIndex;

                    for (var i = this.lineDatasets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        dataArray = this.datasets[i].points;
                        dataIndex = helpers.indexOf(dataArray, ChartElements[0]);
                        if (dataIndex !== -1){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(dataIndex === -1)
                    {
                        for (i = this.barDatasets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            dataArray = this.datasets[i].bars;
                            dataIndex = helpers.indexOf(dataArray, ChartElements[0]);
                            if (dataIndex !== -1){
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var tooltipLabels = [],
                        tooltipColors = [],
                        medianPosition = (function(index) {

                            // Get all the points at that particular index
                            var Elements = [],
                                dataCollection,
                                xPositions = [],
                                yPositions = [],
                                xMax,
                                yMax,
                                xMin,
                                yMin;
                            helpers.each(this.lineDatasets, function(dataset){
                                dataCollection = dataset.points;
                                if (dataCollection[dataIndex] && dataCollection[dataIndex].hasValue()){
                                    Elements.push(dataCollection[dataIndex]);
                                }
                            });
                            helpers.each(this.barDatasets, function(dataset){
                                dataCollection = dataset.bars;
                                if (dataCollection[dataIndex] && dataCollection[dataIndex].hasValue()){
                                    Elements.push(dataCollection[dataIndex]);
                                }
                            });

                            helpers.each(Elements, function(element) {
                                xPositions.push(element.x);
                                yPositions.push(element.y);


                                //Include any colour information about the element
                                tooltipLabels.push(helpers.template(this.options.multiTooltipTemplate, element));
                                tooltipColors.push({
                                    fill: element._saved.fillColor || element.fillColor,
                                    stroke: element._saved.strokeColor || element.strokeColor
                                });

                            }, this);

                            yMin = helpers.min(yPositions);
                            yMax = helpers.max(yPositions);

                            xMin = helpers.min(xPositions);
                            xMax = helpers.max(xPositions);

                            return {
                                x: (xMin > this.chart.width/2) ? xMin : xMax,
                                y: (yMin + yMax)/2
                            };
                        }).call(this, dataIndex);

                    new Chart.MultiTooltip({
                        x: medianPosition.x,
                        y: medianPosition.y,
                        xPadding: this.options.tooltipXPadding,
                        yPadding: this.options.tooltipYPadding,
                        xOffset: this.options.tooltipXOffset,
                        fillColor: this.options.tooltipFillColor,
                        textColor: this.options.tooltipFontColor,
                        fontFamily: this.options.tooltipFontFamily,
                        fontStyle: this.options.tooltipFontStyle,
                        fontSize: this.options.tooltipFontSize,
                        titleTextColor: this.options.tooltipTitleFontColor,
                        titleFontFamily: this.options.tooltipTitleFontFamily,
                        titleFontStyle: this.options.tooltipTitleFontStyle,
                        titleFontSize: this.options.tooltipTitleFontSize,
                        cornerRadius: this.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
                        labels: tooltipLabels,
                        legendColors: tooltipColors,
                        legendColorBackground : this.options.multiTooltipKeyBackground,
                        title: ChartElements[0].label,
                        chart: this.chart,
                        ctx: this.chart.ctx
                    }).draw();

                } else {
                    each(ChartElements, function(Element) {
                        var tooltipPosition = Element.tooltipPosition();
                        new Chart.Tooltip({
                            x: Math.round(tooltipPosition.x),
                            y: Math.round(tooltipPosition.y),
                            xPadding: this.options.tooltipXPadding,
                            yPadding: this.options.tooltipYPadding,
                            fillColor: this.options.tooltipFillColor,
                            textColor: this.options.tooltipFontColor,
                            fontFamily: this.options.tooltipFontFamily,
                            fontStyle: this.options.tooltipFontStyle,
                            fontSize: this.options.tooltipFontSize,
                            caretHeight: this.options.tooltipCaretSize,
                            cornerRadius: this.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
                            text: template(this.options.tooltipTemplate, Element),
                            chart: this.chart
                        }).draw();
                    }, this);
                }
            }
            return this;
        },
    });


}).call(this);
//here ends the LineBar
```

Comment: charts.js now supports combined bar and line chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811425/chart-js-how-to-get-combined-bar-and-line-charts/34987415#34987415

Comment: @ChiragB cheers will update my answer to reflect mine is for 1.x

Comment: @Quince Thank you for a great solution. For people like me who have a lot of charts generated using version 1.0.2 in the same page and don't want to switch, this is very useful. However, unlike chart.js v2.0 implementation, I don't see two Y-axis. Is this something that can be done with your code?

Comment: @DMEM yes the last thing I added to the fork on github was a multi y-axis feature

Answer (score 18):

With Chart.js 2.0 you do it like this:

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',       // set the default type
  data: {
    datasets: [{
                     // default type will be used
      data: []
    }, {

      type: 'line',  // override the default type
      data: []          
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: I've discovered that a default "bar" graph can add lines, however a default "line" graph cannot add bars.

Answer (score 14):

New version of Charts.js (v2.0) supports combined Bar and Line Chart.

v2.0 is currently in Beta

Link to [Plunker](http://goo.gl/Igwoyh)

Answer (score 2):

One minor code addition is needed. In the "buildScale" section, you need to include the data from eachPoints as well. This is, because calculatedY is only using the data from bar to determine the height; the data using line is ignored. If the data using the line is higher than the data using bar, the line graph will be cut off at the top.

```
buildScale : function(labels){
    var self = this;

    var dataTotal = function(){
        var values = [];
        self.eachBars(function(bar){
            values.push(bar.value);
        });
// missing code ↓↓↓
        self.eachPoints(function(point){
            values.push(point.value);
        });
// missing code ↑↑↑
        return values;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

but we want to show gridlines

```
var scaleOptions = {


lineColor : this.options.scaleLineColor,

// missing code ↓↓↓

showHorizontalLines: this.options.scaleShowHorizontalLines,
showVerticalLines: this.options.scaleShowVerticalLines,

//missing code ↑↑↑

}
```

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me to change the z-index of lines and bars. Swap the next two code blocks:

```
helpers.each(this.barDatasets, function (dataset, datasetIndex) ... , this);
helpers.each(this.lineDatasets, function (dataset, datasetIndex) ... , this);
```

Like this:

```
helpers.each(this.lineDatasets, function (dataset, datasetIndex) ... , this);
helpers.each(this.barDatasets, function (dataset, datasetIndex) ... , this);
```

Good luck.