# How do I draw a vertical line on a horizontal bar chart with ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

There are many examples of extending a Chart to include a line, both horizontal and vertical. However, I have not found a way to draw a vertical line with a horizontal bar chart.

1. [Horizontal line on horizontal line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092489/chart-js-draw-horizontal-line)
2. [Vertical line on
   horizontal line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256695/chart-js-drawing-an-arbitrary-vertical-line)
3. [Horizontal line on vertical bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811425/chart-js-how-to-get-combined-bar-and-line-charts)

There is not a "vertical line chart" option like there is a "horizontal bar chart" option. How do I combine a horizontal bar chart with a vertical line?

[Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

The result would have a bar dataset and a line dataset that can be used on the same chart using the same axis like below:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ChartJS supports custom plugins. Create a plug in that will read a new property from the chart options and draw the line at the specified index.

[See it on Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubR7Luf4NisgxqR2sVUr?p=preview)

```js
 //Create the plug in
  var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.horizontalBar.prototype.draw;
  Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.horizontalBar.prototype, {
  
      draw: function () {
          originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);
  
          var chart = this.chart;
          var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
  
          var index = chart.config.options.lineAtIndex;
          if (index) {
  
              var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
              var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
  
              var x1 = xaxis.getPixelForValue(index);                       
              var y1 = yaxis.top;                                                   
  
              var x2 = xaxis.getPixelForValue(index);                       
              var y2 = yaxis.bottom;                                        
  
              ctx.save();
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
              ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
              ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
              ctx.stroke();
  
              ctx.restore();
          }
      }
  });

//Set up the chart data
  var data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
          {
              label: "My First dataset",
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1,
              data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
          }
      ]
  };

  //Load Chart
  var ctx = $("#myChart");
  var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: data,
      options: {
          //Set the index of the value where you want to draw the line
          lineAtIndex: 60,
          legend: {
            display: false
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js'></script>

    <script src="horizontalBarPlugin.js"></script>
    <script src="buildChart.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Joel Richman, do you know how we can hover on the red vertical line so that it displays its desired value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It's a horizontal line with vertical bar charts - so the opposite of you case. But maybe you can derive something useful out of it:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#chartContainer',
 tooltip: {
        grouped: false 
    }, 
data: {

    columns: [

        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ['data3', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data4', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ['data5', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ['data6', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ['data7', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ['diif1', null, null, 700 ],
        ['diif2', null, null, 1200]
    ],
    types:{
     "data1" :"bar",
        "data2" :"bar",
        "data3" :"bar",
        "data4" :"bar",
        "data5" :"bar",
        "data6" :"bar",
        "data7" :"bar",
         "diff1" : "line",
        "diff2" : "line"

  },
     order:null,
    groups: [
        ['data1', 'data2','data3', 'data4'],
        ['data5', 'data6','data7']
    ],
     onclick: function (d, element) { 
         var name=d.name;
         drilldown(name);
     }

},
   grid: {
       y: {
        lines:[{value:1400,text:1400}, 
              {value: 1450,text: 1450}
             ]
         }
    } 
});


function drilldown(name){
 alert('Call for ' +name);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nxcfzb9/12/

I'm looking for something similar to you but not with horizontal bar charts, but timespan bars, if you've got an idea, please let me know:
[How do I change or add the vertical line on a tooltip of a c3 graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830359/how-do-i-change-or-add-the-vertical-line-on-a-tooltip-of-a-c3-graph)