# Extend chart.js horizontal bar graph to include a vertical line

Tags: charts, html5-canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to add a vertical line to at a set point of a horizontal bar chart.  Examples I've found do not seem to apply to charts.js 2.  Even if I create a new chart type and use the horizontalBar draw method with no modifications, the chart won't draw.

```
Chart.controllers.horizontalBarWithLine = Chart.controllers.horizontalBar.extend({
    draw: function () {
        Chart.controllers.horizontalBar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain how to extend this chart?

Here's my current attemp: https://jsfiddle.net/dwelch/6f1gfog2/

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to this question.  I think this is what you are looking for:

[How do I draw a vertical line on a horizontal bar chart with ChartJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256605/how-do-i-draw-a-vertical-line-on-a-horizontal-bar-chart-with-chartjs/39280051#39280051)